# How can a run a query on one table based on the results of a query on another table?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, join

I'm not sure that a normal join will help me in the situation I have:

I have two tables as part of an app I'm building: one just lists a `username` in the *first column* and a `friend's username` in the *second column*. This table is strictly for keeping track of users and the users with whom they are friends.

The second table has 4 columns, `username`, `last name`, `first name` and `password`. This table is strictly for keeping track of registered users' login and personal information.

I want to run a query on the first table to find all friends of the logged in user that contain a search term passed to the URL by javascript, which I have done:

```
SELECT friend FROM friends WHERE user='$user' AND friend 
LIKE '%" . $term . "%'" //$user == $_SESSION['user']
```

This returns a list of usernames of the friends of the logged in user from the "friends" table that contain the search term $term.

Next, I want to run a query that returns the `first name`, `last name` and `username` of all users who match the first query (the friends of the logged in user) and whose first name or last name contain the same search term, $term, passed to the url by javascript. This query must be on the "user" table, since only it contains first and last names.

I'm just not sure how to join the tables and run the query in such a way as to get this information only for friends of the user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.username 
FROM friends JOIN users ON friends.friend = users.username
WHERE friends.user = '$user'
AND friends.friend LIKE '%$term%';
```

Comment: This answer ultimately was the closest, although I wanted the search term to match the first or last name rather than the friend's username. Ultimately, the code I used was `("SELECT users.firstname, users.lastname, users.user FROM friends JOIN users ON friends.friend = users.user WHERE friends.user = '$user' AND users.firstname LIKE '%" . $term . "%' OR users.lastname LIKE '%" . $term . "%'")`

Comment: Ah, ok.  Well I'm glad you got it figured out.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use IN in this situation.

```
SELECT firstname, lastname, username from tablename WHERE username IN( 
   select you have posted
);
```

I believe this may result in what you want. If not you will need to use a JOIN.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a normal join or with a subquery.

Subquery:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, username FROM users
WHERE username IN (
    SELECT friend FROM friends
    WHERE user='$user'
    AND friend  LIKE "'%" . $term . "%'")
```

Implicit join:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, username FROM users, friends
WHERE friend=username
AND user='$user'
AND friend LIKE "'%" . $term . "%'"
```

Explicit join:

```
SELECT first_name, last_name, users.username FROM friends
WHERE friend LIKE "'%" . $term . "%'" AND user='$user'
LEFT JOIN users ON user=username
```

Comment: This is really close to what I'm looking for, but in this query, I want to return results where firstname or lastname is like $term, not where friend is like $term.

Answer (score 0):

please modify the name of the fields that suit your needs:

```
SELECT username, lastname, firstname
FROM `SecondTable`
WHERE username in
    (SELECT friend as username 
    FROM friends 
    WHERE user='$user' AND 
          friend LIKE '%" . $term . "%'")
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.username LoggedInUsersUserName, u2.username FriendsUserName 
from users u join
     friends f on f.username = u.username join
     users u2 on u2.username = f.username
```

You should be able to extrapolate whatever you need from that.

Comment: FYI, I just posted this because while I know it's not the exact answer you're looking for, I thought it would be good for you to realize that you can join to the same table more than once in a query to solve problems like this.